# Karaf - Hibernate - MariaDB "Could not complete schema update" error

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mariadb, apache-karaf, karaf

I'm trying to setup a project with **Karaf 4.0.4** + **Hibernate 4.3.6.Final** and I'm using **MariaDB 10.0.23** as database.

I have followed and tried [this tutorial](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/tree/master/db/examplejpa) but:

- Instead of using datasource blueprint.xml I want to use pax-jdbc-config  to create a DataSource (since datasource blueprint is deprecated).
- Instead of MySQL, I have to use MariaDB. So I assume I had to change some of the config files to use MariaDB driver

As a result, this is my configuration:

1. **org.ops4j.datasource-sampleprj.cfg**:

   ```
   osgi.jdbc.driver.name=mariadb
   osgi.jdbc.driver.class=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
   url=jdbc:mysql://DB_SERVER:3306/sampleprjdb
   dataSourceName=sampleprj
   databaseName=sampleprjdb
   user=myuser
   password=mypassword
   ```

I'm certain my database credentials and database name are correct.

2. sample-prj bundle > **persistence.xml**:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
   <persistence version="2.0"
       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
       <persistence-unit name="sampleprj" transaction-type="JTA">
           <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
           <jta-data-source>
               osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/sampleprj)      
           </jta-data-source>
           <properties>
               <property name="hibernate.dialect"     value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
               <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
               <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
               <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
           </properties>
       </persistence-unit>
   </persistence>
   ```

In `<jta-data-source>` element, I have tried both the value above and `osgi:service/sampleprj` but they did not work.
I have also tried different `hibernate.dialect`s as most of the schema update errors caused by incorrect dialect.

3. sample-prj bundle > **blueprint.xml**:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <blueprint default-activation="eager"
       xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.0.0" xmlns:tx="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.0.0"

       xsi:schemaLocation="
               http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 
               http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance     http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance 
               http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.0.0 http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.0.0 
               http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.0.0 http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.0.0 ">

       <bean id="dbService"
           class="org.sample.project.persistence.mariadb.impl.DbServiceImpl">
           <jpa:context unitname="sampleprj" property="em"/>
           <tx:transaction method="*" value="Required" />
       </bean>

       <service ref="dbService" interface="org.sample.project.IDbService" />

   </blueprint>
   ```
4. sample-prj bundle > **pom.xml**:

   ```
   <project>

   ...

   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
               <extensions>true</extensions>
               <configuration>
                   <instructions>
                       <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                       <Meta-Persistence>META-INF/persistence.xml</Meta-Persistence>
                       <Bundle-Version>1.0.0</Bundle-Version>
                       <Bundle-ManifestVersion>2</Bundle-ManifestVersion>
                       <Manifest-Version>1</Manifest-Version>
                       <Import-Package>
                       org.apache.felix.service.command;version="[0.6,1)",
                       org.apache.felix.gogo.commands;version="[0.6,1)",
                       org.apache.karaf.shell.console;version="[2.2,4)",
                       org.hibernate.proxy,
                       javassist.util.proxy,
                       *
                       </Import-Package>
                   </instructions>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>

   ...

   </project>
   ```

I can also confirm resulting Manifest.MF contains `Meta-Persistence` attribute.

5. On **Karaf (clean) start**, I use these commands to install dependent bundles:

   ```
   feature:repo-add mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-features/0.5.0/xml/features
   feature:install transaction jndi pax-jdbc-mariadb pax-jdbc-config pax-jdbc-pool-dbcp2 jpa hibernate
   ```

When I use `bundle:list`, all bundles seem to be installed and are **active** so far.

6. Finally, I use this command to install my sample bundle:

   ```
   bundle:install mvn:org.sample.prj/sample-prj/1.0
   ```

But it prints these log messages:

```
2016-02-22 15:38:44,035 | ERROR | pool-36-thread-1 | SchemaUpdate                     | 199 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.4.GA | HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:227)[188:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178)[188:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522)[188:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)[188:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)[189:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)[189:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)[188:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)[189:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.osgi.OsgiPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(OsgiPersistenceProvider.java:112)[190:org.hibernate.osgi:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.PersistenceProviderTracker.createAndCloseDummyEMF(PersistenceProviderTracker.java:105)[79:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:2.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.PersistenceProviderTracker.addingService(PersistenceProviderTracker.java:85)[79:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:2.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.PersistenceProviderTracker.addingService(PersistenceProviderTracker.java:44)[79:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:2.3.0]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:941)[org.osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:870)[org.osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)[org.osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)[org.osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:318)[org.osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:261)[org.osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.PersistenceBundleTracker.trackProvider(PersistenceBundleTracker.java:106)[79:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:2.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.PersistenceBundleTracker.findPersistenceUnits(PersistenceBundleTracker.java:90)[79:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:2.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.PersistenceBundleTracker.addingBundle(PersistenceBundleTracker.java:69)[79:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:2.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.PersistenceBundleTracker.addingBundle(PersistenceBundleTracker.java:40)[79:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:2.3.0]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:469)[org.osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:415)[org.osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)[org.osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)[org.osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker.open(BundleTracker.java:156)[org.osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.Activator.start(Activator.java:43)[79:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:2.3.0]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:697)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2226)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2144)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:984)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.startBundle(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1199)[9:org.apache.karaf.features.core:4.0.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:840)[9:org.apache.karaf.features.core:4.0.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1089)[9:org.apache.karaf.features.core:4.0.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl$1.call(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:985)[9:org.apache.karaf.features.core:4.0.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)[:1.7.0_45]
```

I suspect that there is some missing or wrong configuration here. What am I missing?

Thanks, Emre.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue in Aries JPA 2. Charlie Mordant just wrote me a mail today with results of some tests he did with Aries JPA 2. He mentioned a similar behaviour with hibernate were he also wanted the schema to be created by the persistence provider.

The main difference to the tutorial is probably that the tutorial uses an embedded that does not require credentials to log in. I will try to reproduce the issue in a test in Aries JPA. Can you open an issue for this in the [Apache Aries Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARIES)?